# How to write the equivalent Python encryption/decryption functions as the C# ones so that Python/C# could decrypt each other encrypted string?

Tags: python, c#, encryption

Have two programs, one is developed in C#.NET, having the below C# encryption/decryption functions:

```
    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string keyString)
    {
        byte[] cipherData;
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
        aes.GenerateIV();
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform cipher = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cipher, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                {
                    sw.Write(plainText);
                }
            }
            cipherData = ms.ToArray();
        }

        byte[] combinedData = new byte[aes.IV.Length + cipherData.Length];
        Array.Copy(aes.IV, 0, combinedData, 0, aes.IV.Length);
        Array.Copy(cipherData, 0, combinedData, aes.IV.Length, cipherData.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(combinedData);
    }


    public static string Decrypt(string combinedString, string keyString)
    {
        string plainText;
        byte[] combinedData = Convert.FromBase64String(combinedString);
        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
        byte[] iv = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[combinedData.Length - iv.Length];
        Array.Copy(combinedData, iv, iv.Length);
        Array.Copy(combinedData, iv.Length, cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform decipher = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decipher, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                {
                    plainText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return plainText;
        }
    }
```

Another program is using Python, need to decrypt the encrypted string from the C# program.

What are the Python encryption/decryption functions so that Python's decryption function could decrypt the encrypted string by the above C# encryption function, also C#'s decryption function could decrypt the encrypted string by Python's encryption function?

Comment: SO is not a code porting service. Please post your Python code and describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The below are the Python functions worked for me:

```
import Crypto.Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad, pad


def encrypt(plain_text, key_string):
    raw = pad(plain_text.encode(), AES.block_size)
    iv = Crypto.Random.get_random_bytes(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key_string, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))


def decrypt(combined_string, key_string):
    enc = base64.b64decode(combined_string)
    iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key_string, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    msg = unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:]), AES.block_size)
    return msg.decode()
```